# How do I create a skin miniature in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I create a skin miniature in Minecraft? A miniature is a small preview of a skin. To understand what I'm talking about look at [this](http://minecraftskins.com) site.

Comment: That site also had a 3d model viewer. I imagine both of those were generated with an in-house app.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you clarify the exact difference between a skin and a skin miniature?

Comment: A skin miniature is a png file in a size of 32x32 pixels, which displays the front part of your gaming character. The miniature can be used on the web sites, which provides an ability for visitors to download the Minecraft skins. It facilitates the skin search. I'm looking for a script or an utility which can translate a native skin file to the miniature.

Answer (score 2):

after some time in jsfiddle, I made [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wet8Y/2/embedded/result/). If it doesn't work, make sure your browser is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it reads the skin template you uploaded, reads it, and creates a skin miniature based on it for the website. If you have an account, try to load a test skin and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Photoshop, you can use [Smart Objects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/11.0/WSCCBCA4AB-7821-4986-BC03-4D1045EF2A57a.html), one for each body part. Updates to one instance of a smart object affect all others, so simply keep one set laid out as per `skin.png` and another set laid out as a miniature. You'll have to keep both your miniature and skin png in the same file and export the slices separately.

Given the time and effort of setting this up though this is going to be a lot more trouble than it's worth unless you're making a *lot* of skins...